# Why is pagination dots not showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-pagination

I am using `jquery.pagination.js` plugin.

I have 100 pages. The first and last page are numbers are showing, but the dots are not showing. Please check the screen shot and code.

```
$("#Pagination").pagination(num_entries, {
    items_per_page : 10,
    num_display_entries : 2,
    num_edge_entries : 1,
    current_page : pageIndex-1,
    //link_to : path +"?"+param
    callback : paginationCallback
});

function paginationCallback(page_index, jq) {

}
```

[image]
[image]

Any default options having for show the dots symbol?

Comment: Or you don't want to be smarter, but want to be productive.

Comment: You should consider using [**simplePagination**](https://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/) instead, it contains your desired 'dots' icon per default.

Comment: Thanks to all for your response. i will use my own scripts.

Comment: Can you recreate this in a http://jsfiddle.net ? A simplified version will suffice or give us a link as to which pagination plugin you are using

Comment: "i will use my own scripts"....you are already using external script....it wont make much difference if you another plugin..i could easily trace simple pagination plugin as told by urbz....can you give a link to the your plugin documentation page..

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all valuable replies. I used bootstrap pagination plugin. its working good. http://www.jplugins.net/twbs-pagination/?demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML code:

```
<div id="selector">
    <ul class="selector">
        <li>
            <p>One</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Two</p>
        </li>
        <li>
        <p>Three</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Four</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Five</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Six</p>
        </li>
        <li>
           <p>Seven</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Eight</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And JS Script:

```
$(function() {
        $(selector).pagination({
             items: 100,
             itemsOnPage: 10,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme'
        })
});
```

Here is a [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/da6wj2jv/1/). I just added  style and javascript sources from their github repo.

Comment: Hi, In the working demo link i didnt see any pagination. check it and send me correct link.

Comment: Hi, In JSFIDDLE i clicked the "jQuery UI 1.10.3". now its working good. thanks

Comment: I've checked and it's work for me. Anyway, I'm glad to help you.